# Why SVM works better when n≈m or n>m?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, model

**n**: no. of features
**m**: no. of training examples

I was going through the machine learning course of AndrewNg and in one of his lectures he talks about which classifier to use in different scenarios. He mentions that if n>=m or n≈m then support vector machine could be used but not when n is small and m is very large.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the kernel matrix $K$ (positive semi-definite) is $m \times m$.

When number of instances is not large, it can be stored in memory and we can effectively optimize the SVM objective function. If number of instance $m$ is large, say 1 million, then the kernel matrix is 1 million by 1 million an the SVM optimization is hard to solve.

---

SVM optimization to solve $\alpha$,

$$
\max_{0 \leq \alpha \leq c} ~ \sum_i \alpha_i - \frac 1 2 \sum_i \sum_j \alpha_i\alpha_j y_i y_j K_{i,j}
$$

When number of instance is large, storing the kernel matrix and performing optimization.

On the other hand, for linear model,  For example, linear regression number of features $n$ matters more. QR decomposition on data matrix with 1 million rows and 2 columns takes seconds, but not the other way around.

Comment: True, but only if you are actually using the kernel trick, which is not mentioned in the question. A linear SVM can do away with that (and in practice many popular implementations of the linear SVM do).